# Access to path is denied, Silverlight 4

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight-4.0, access-denied

I am trying to access a WCF service located on the server side of my solution. It works fine in Windows 7 environment but in Windows XP environment, it throws this error, I have done all the security settings in terms of permissions but it seems like it is Silverlight thing and I am missing a critical setting.

Access to the path 'C:\TempJay\04_Ver\Bookmarks\Bookmarks.Web\Config\Tools.xml' is denied.

I am looking for some feedback on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Jay

Comment: can you please add more description to it?

Comment: what exactly is throwing the error? I am thinking this is more connected with system settings on XP machine (file access policies) and WCF than to SL4.0 cause silverlight can hardly ever access files on that path unless its running out of browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the clientaccesspolicy.xml on WCF side, 100% permissive and test the application. This is to narrow down for sure if its a config setting or application logic. A sample file I always use for troubleshooting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Microsoft's networking documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645029(v=VS.95).aspx

is pretty exhaustive and might yield some troubleshooting steps I'm sure. Particularly the sections on restrictions.

Comment: Thansk for the input. These steps resolve the problem: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/238022/589468.aspx/1?Access+to+path+is+denied